# Plotting system load from timestamped event log file

Tags: logging, plot, gnuplot

I have a log file like so:

> 40624.4866625463#Event1
>   40624.4866623727#Event1
>   40624.4866623727#Event1
>   40624.4866625463#Event1
>   40624.4866625463#Event1
>   40624.4866627315#Event1
>   40624.4866627315#Event1
>   40624.4866627315#Event1
>   40624.4866627315#Event1

Where:

- the first number is a date time. (Integer is the day number and fraction is the time.)
- `#` is the field delimeter
- `Event1` - is a description of the event.

What I would like to do is graph the number of events within a moving time window. The window will be around 15s but must be easily variable. So the graph will be rate of events versus time.

I would like to use `gnuplot` but am open to using any other plotting tools that run on windows.

Many thanks.

Comment: I have a few questions concerning your problem: 1. Why use the average number of events, when you actually know the number events? 2. What do you mean by "easily variable"? Maybe you could post a sketch to visualize what you are aiming for?

Comment: @Wolton - You are right I don't need to divide by the time window since it will be constant. Total number of events per time moving window will be fine. I'm unable to post a picture (proxy limited) but I am looking for a line graph which expresses the load on my system over time. By variable I mean for one plot the window will be set to 15s but another plot might be set to 1s window.

Comment: What programming environment are you using?  I.e. is it a unix (cygwin) shell with the various elements there, or is it a "real" application?  Also, what time units is the time represented in (milli-seconds, micro-seconds, seconds)?  You should be able to do this pretty easily using perl.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a gnuplot expert, but I think what you are trying to do is not possible with gnuplot or at least not in a nice and easy way. What gnuplot needs is a data file containing numbers to plot them accordingly. If I understand you correctly, you try to sum up events through an arbitrary period of time and plot that number in some *moving window*.

The summing up is something that gnuplot does not support. It is possible to call shell commands but I would suggest you take your favorite scripting language and process the data you have available. Then you might export that data to a data file gnuplot can handle.

**Edit**:

An other alternative I just came across is [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/index.html). I have not used it myself but it looks like it has a lot of potential. I'll definitely take a look at it some time, until then maybe you can check it out and report how easy it is to pick up ;)

Comment: Thanks Woltan. But there must be some tool out there that supports this. It doesn't have to be gnuplot. Of course your method will work and this is what I have done, I was just hoping for a more elegant approach.

Comment: Hi T33C, I don't think that there is a tool out there that has the exact interface you are looking for. I think it is more likely that you have to provide an interface yourself either by scripting it or by exporting the data in a different format. In my opinion it is not the job of a plotting utility to become a scripting language but to support a basic set of data formats, where I suppose yours does not qualify as such.